# How to limit the range of keys returned by GeoFire for Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I followed [this](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java) documentation end-to-end and have also asked more than 6-7 questions related to this problem here on StackOverflow. I have also written a mail to Firebase support.

I'm saving some data along with `GeoFire` coordinates in `FirebaseDatabase`. It is getting saved like this:

[image]

Now, I'm trying to retrieve it using this code:

```
geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(currentLatDouble, currentLngDouble), 0.5);

        geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {

    databaseReference.child("requests").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            Map<String, String> newRequest = (Map<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                            imageUID = newRequest.get("imageUIDh");
                            hDescription = newRequest.get("hDescription");
                            currentLat = newRequest.get("currentLat");
                            currentLng = newRequest.get("currentLng");
                            postedBy = newRequest.get("postedBy");
                            postedAtTime = newRequest.get("postedAtTime");
                            postedOnDate = newRequest.get("postedOnDate");
                            utcFormatDateTime = newRequest.get("utcFormatDateTime");

                            String timeStr = utcFormatDateTime;
                            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                            df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
                            Date date = null;
                            try {
                                // error on the line below
                                date = df.parse(timeStr);
                                //
                            } catch (ParseException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
                            final String persisted = df.format(date);

                            // Parse string from DB - UTC timezone
                            Date parsed = null;
                            try {
                                parsed = df.parse(persisted);
                            } catch (ParseException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            // Now convert to whatever timezone for display purposes
                            final SimpleDateFormat displayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
                            displayFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

                            formattedTime = displayFormat.format(parsed);

                            prepareDataForRequests();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                                    .make(coordinatorLayout, databaseError.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                            snackbar.setDuration(Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            snackbar.show();
                            progressBarLoadingRequests.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    });
}

            @Override
            public void onKeyExited(String key) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onGeoQueryReady() {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "geoQueries retrieved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error retriving geoquery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

The problem is that the posts which was posted from 1000 kms away from me is also getting retrieved as well the post which was posted from 0.1 kms away from me is also getting retrieved, though only the posts which was posted within 0.5 kms should have been shown.

How to achieve this?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen you edited the question, why not you answer it?

Comment: There are too many parts to the question. If you reduce the problem to a minimum, you will have a better chance that somebody will be able to help. Asking the same thing repeatedly does not increase that chance.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I just want to know what am I doing wrong with my code? I have provided the code. This is the only part. I have provided the structure from my database. What else is needed to make it more detailed?

Comment: The solution if you get no response is not to add more details, it is to reduce the problem. If your problem is that you get keys outside of the range, the other value listeners are not needed to reproduce that. Start from scratch and reproduce the problem with minimal code. Then share that code. All of this (and other reasons why this may help you solve your own problem) is pretty well described in [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen ok, please tell me that whether my approach of saving the data with respective geofire is appropriate or not?